# Maximum of a simple random walk

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-walk

$M_n=\max\{S_k : k= 1,...n\}$

where $S_n$ is a simple random walk, $S_n = \sum_{i=0}^n X_i$ and $X_i$ is a Bernoulli random variable where $P(X = 1) = P(X = -1) = 0.5$

Prove that $P(M_n \geq r \bigcap S_n = v) = P(S_n = 2r - v)$.

I know that this requires using the reflection principle but I'm not sure where to go from here. We talked about this in class but I didn't understand the concept so I wanted to see if someone could clarify.

Comment: I know that drawing drawing drawing helps a lot with these kind of exercises.

Comment: It looks like you need to assume something like $0 \leq v \leq r$ as well; is that the case?  Otherwise consider $n = 2, v = 4, r =2$.